# How do I get the ActualWidth of the GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, datatemplate, actualwidth

I have the following XAML:

```
<GridView x:Key="myGridView">
    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
</GridView>
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
</DateTemplate>
```

When I use it, I want the contentpresenter to have the same width as the GridViewColumn. So far, I've tried using the RelativeSource binding but I can't seem to get the GridViewColumn at all.

How do I get the `ActualWidth` from the parent `GridViewColumn` from the `ContentPresenter` in my `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `GridView` is that there is no notion of cells as visual elements in the generated control hierarchy. In order for your `ContentPresenter` to be wide as the column you should set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `ListViewItem` to `Stretch`. This way the `ContentPresenter` will stretch to the available width, which is the width of the column.

Here is a sample XAML which illustrates this:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="leftTemplate">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="rightTemplate">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <GridView x:Key="myGridView">
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" CellTemplate="{StaticResource rightTemplate}" Header="Right"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" CellTemplate="{StaticResource leftTemplate}" Header="Left"/>
         </GridView>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <ListView Margin="10" View="{StaticResource myGridView}">
         <ListViewItem Content="item 1"/>
         <ListViewItem Content="item 2"/>
         <ListViewItem Content="item 3"/>
         <ListViewItem Content="item 4"/>
         <ListViewItem Content="item 5"/>
      </ListView>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```